# AJAX File Upload with XMLHttpRequest that support i.e 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a file using ajax. The code below works perfectly on all browsers except i.e 9 and previous versions. Unfortunately I am forced to support these browsers so I am wondering how I could modify this code so it will work on i.e.

I have seen some posts suggest using an iframe but i fail to see how this fixes my problem.

I have tried using fileInput.name since it seems that i.e doesn't allow me to have an array of files, this meant that I could actually get to the line where it sends but I wasn't sure what that line should be. xhr.send(fileInput); didn't seem to work.

Also attempted using formdata but then also fould that ie9 didn't support that.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <script>
    function uploadFile(fileInput, label1, label2, filename) {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById(fileInput);

        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhr.open('POST', 'Create/Upload');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
        //Appending file information in Http headers

        //xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', filename);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileInput.files[0].name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileInput.files[0].type);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', fileInput.files[0].size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Type', label1);
        //Sending file in XMLHttpRequest
        xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);

        //xhr.send(fileInput);


        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                $('#' + label1).text(xhr.responseText.replace(/\"/g, ""));
                document.getElementById(label1).style.color = "green";
                document.getElementById(label2).style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                $('#' + label1).text("File upload failed");
                document.getElementById(label1).style.color = "red";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('uploaderAuto').onsubmit = function () {

        myfile = $('#fileInputAuto').val();
        var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
        ext = ext.toLowerCase();
        if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "docx" || ext == "doc" || ext == "odf" || ext == "rtf") {
            uploadFile('fileInputAuto', 'Auto', "AutoView", myfile);
        } else {
            alert("The following is a list of accepted file types:\n\n - Word Document (*.doc)\n - Word Document (*.docx)\n - Portable Document Format (*.pdf)\n - Open Document Format (*.odf)\n - Rich Text Format (*.rtf)\n\nPlease choose a file with one of these file types.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('uploaderOther1').onsubmit = function () {
        myfile = $('#fileInputOther1').val();
        uploadFile('fileInputOther1', 'Other1', 'Other1View', myfile);
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('uploaderOther2').onsubmit = function () {
        myfile = $('#fileInputOther2').val();
        uploadFile('fileInputOther2', 'Other2', 'Other2View', myfile);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the script from here: http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/ and it works very well.

I was using asp.net server side so this tutorial helped: http://totalpict.com/b/asp.net%20generic/5/34396